# rails4 scope syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting following error after I added active-admin.

Error: syntax error, unexpected '|' scope :search, ->(sname) { |query| ^

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :softwares
  scope :visible, -> (visible) { where(:visible => true)}
  scope :invisible,-> (visible) { where(:visible => false)}
  scope :sorted, -> (sname) {order("softwares.sname ASC")}  
  scope :newest_first, -> (created_at) {order("softwares.created_at DESC"  )}
  scope :search, ->(sname) { |query|
    where(["sname LIKE ?","%#{query}%"])
  }
end
```

**Previous code **

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :softwares
  scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true)}
  scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false)}
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("softwares.sname ASC")}
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("softwares.created_at DESC"  )}
  scope :search, lambda { |query|
    where(["sname LIKE ?","%#{query}%"])
  }
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: PS: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Comment: @muistooshort: But be careful, [class methods might have a different behavior than the DSL scope](http://ruby-journal.com/rails/the-difference-between-activerecord-scope-dsl-and-class-method/)...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are confused about the use of the short and the normal syntax of lambdas.

The long form:

```
lambda { |argument| ... }
```

The short syntax:

```
->(argument) { ... }
```

In scopes there is not need to pass an argument, when do not use that argument in the query.

Change your code to:

```
  scope :visible,       -> { where(:visible => true) }
  scope :invisible,     -> { where(:visible => false) }
  scope :sorted,        -> { order('softwares.sname ASC') }  
  scope :newest_first,  -> { order("softwares.created_at DESC") }
  scope :search, ->(query) { where('sname LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") }
```

[`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) takes only the scope as a parameter, it does not need a name. Therefore change:

```
default_scope :visible, -> { where(:visible => true)}
```

to

```
default_scope { where(:visible => true) }
```

Comment: I am getting another error after I made the above change. Here is the error: You tried to define a scope named "search" on the model "Category", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name. (ArgumentError)

Comment: That means that there exists another method with the name `search`. Just rename the scope to something else, like `:search_by`...

Comment: Still it is not working, what's wrong in below code?

default_scope :visible, -> { where(:visible => true)}

getting below error:
`default_scope': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: This works well with rest of the lines except last one. I am new to rails and started getting this error when i installed active admin gem. I tried to change the scope :search, ->(query) { where('sname LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") }  to default_scope  { where('sname LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") }. Looks like it is not acceptable. I get following error: undefined local variable or method `query' for #<Class:0x007fd534121e5

Comment: You cannot use a scope as default scope that needs a parameter, because the parameter doesn't exist all the time.

Comment: is there any alternative for this?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you try to achieve. A default scope would scope every query to your database. If you were able to combine a `LIKE` query and a default scope, that would basically mean that you can only parts of your database. You wouldn't (without tricks) not be able to load records that do not match the `LIKE` query. default scope do not really make sense in this context. I advise to read the docs about scopes and default scopes. Normal scopes are used all the time, whereas default scopes serve a different and a very special use case.